# iOS uiwebview fails to load resources from javascript method

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I loading a url in a uiwebview, this urls loads a javascript method with some parameters to show a Map, it works perfectly in all navigators and android.

The ATS policy is configured to load all resources from http, at first it was loading from a http configured server but now we have https configured correctly, but the error is still appearing, we want to know the source of the problem.

I try to debug the information using the simulator and the web inspector enabled but is not clear and it doesn't say anything.

[image: Web inspector information]

1.- It works in safari
2.- iOS 7 fails so is not a iOS 9 problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an error on the server side since you've got an HTTP 500 error. You have to check if you call URL with different parameters when you're on the browser and when you are on the device.

Comment: The parameters are the same, because now we are using a static url, why safari loads differently to uiwebview, it has something turned on that uiwebview doesn't?